# How to get array of data items from custom data rendered bootstrap-vue table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a Data table using BootstrapVue constructed from json `items` and the code is as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table small :fields="fields" :items="items" responsive="sm">
      <!-- A virtual column -->
      <template v-slot:cell(index)="data">
        {{ data.index + 1 }}
      </template>

      <!-- A custom formatted column -->
      <template v-slot:cell(name)="data">
        <b class="text-info">{{ data.value.last.toUpperCase() }}</b>, <b>{{ data.value.first }}</b>
      </template>

      <!-- A virtual composite column -->
      <template v-slot:cell(nameage)="data">
        {{ data.item.name.first }} is {{ data.item.age }} years old
      </template>

      <!-- Optional default data cell scoped slot -->
      <template v-slot:cell()="data">
        <b-form-input v-model="data.value" placeholder="Enter custom value" />
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        outputItems: [],
        fields: [
          // A virtual column that doesn't exist in items
          'index',
          // A column that needs custom formatting
          { key: 'name', label: 'Full Name' },
          // A regular column
          'age',
          // A regular column
          'sex',
          // A virtual column made up from two fields
          { key: 'nameage', label: 'First name and age' }
        ],
        items: [
          { name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Male', age: 42 },
          { name: { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Female', age: 36 },
          { name: { first: 'Rubin', last: 'Kincade' }, sex: 'Male', age: 73 },
          { name: { first: 'Shirley', last: 'Partridge' }, sex: 'Female', age: 62 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The table here is custom rendered from `items` array. My question is .. How to get back array data items from the custom rendered table?

The output of above code looks like

[image]

From this table I want an array of json with new custom rendered data. So my output `outputItems` for above table should look like

```
outputItems = [
  {'Index': 1, 'Full Name': 'DOE,John', 'Age': 42, 'Sex': 'Male', 'First name and age': 'John is 42 years old'},
  {'Index': 2, 'Full Name': 'DOE,Jane', 'Age': 36, 'Sex': 'Female', 'First name and age': 'Jane is 36 years old'},
  {'Index': 3, 'Full Name': 'KINCADE,Rubin', 'Age': 73, 'Sex': 'Male', 'First name and age': 'Rubin is 73 years old'},
  {'Index': 4, 'Full Name': 'PATRIDGE,Shirley', 'Age': 62, 'Sex': '', 'First name and age': 'Shirley is 62 years old'}
]
```

Comment: Aren't those data change when you enter a new value to an input field?

Comment: Can''t you just use `computed`? If you have `items` in your data and you just need to get `outputItems` it can be done with `computed` easily.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov `items` are not updating when input fields in table columns are changed

Comment: You should do something like: `:slot="field.key" slot-scope="data"` and `<b-form-input v-model="data.item[field.key]"></b-form-input>`

Comment: `data.value` (from the scope) is after any formatting has happened and is a copy of the item record value (not a reference to it). To alter the _actual_ item row value, use `v-model="data.item.age"`.  You will also need a specific slot for each input in the row... do not use `v-slot:cell()="data"` fallback slot.  use `v-slot:cell(age)="data"`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table small :fields="fields" :items="items" responsive="sm">
      <!-- A virtual column -->
      <template v-slot:cell(index)="data">
        {{ data.index + 1 }}
      </template>

      <!-- A custom formatted column -->
      <template v-slot:cell(name)="data">
        <b class="text-info">{{ data.value.last.toUpperCase() }}</b>, <b>{{ data.value.first }}</b>
      </template>

      <!-- A virtual composite column -->
      <template v-slot:cell(nameage)="data">
        {{ data.item.name.first }} is {{ data.item.age }} years old
      </template>

      <template v-slot:cell(age)="data">
        <b-form-input v-model="data.item.age" placeholder="Enter age" />
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

*Note:* Every time a user types a character into the input, the table will re-render. This is because of the underlying data model for items being updated (Vue reactivity)